# Database table for tracking user's score history

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I have a database table `User`.

Each user in the database table has a field `score`.

I want to show how the user's score has changed over time.

How do I store this score? Should I create an independent database table `Score` with fields `userId`, `score`, `timestamp`?

Should I still save the rank in the user table, or is it enough to store the rank in the `Score` table? Should I instead have a field `currentScoreId` or something which points at the row in the score database table?

I am using MongoDB, so it's not that easy to use relational queries, but I think it seems stupid to store the rank both in a separate database table and in the user table.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider having a schema like this, if the list of score for each user is not that large:

```
{
   userId: "String",
   currentScore: { // this would be the copy of the most recent score
       score: "Integer",
       timeStamp: "Date"
   },
   scores: [ // an array of all scores of this user
       {
          score: "Integer",
          timestamp: "Date"
       },
       ...
   ]
}
```

Database modeling is different in MongoDB. You don't have the easy table join as in traditional relational database.

As of the ranking, do you want to save it as a separate field?  I would think that would be hard to update all the ranking in db, even with traditional db.  So above i added a `currentScore` field, and you can sort based on that field, and generate ranking on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

the answer given by Peter is good for many cases but if there is unlimited number of scores (that would exceed the 16MB / document) consider the following link

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Otherwise this is a good approach :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Answer (score -1):

Here i am assuming that your table (user) look like:

**User = columns(userId, score)**
Create separate table called as 
**user_audit = column(identifierPK,userId,score,timestamp)**
Write trigger on user table to populate user audit history.

Here you can add another column of user table and track its history overtime.

Another option is:

**UserScoreAudit = columns(user_id,oldScore,newScore,timestamp)**

**Generic Audit Table = columns(actorId, oldValue, newValue, tableName, fieldName,timestamp)**